# error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'

Tags: c, prototype, struct, typedef, header-files

I have the following header file, but keep on getting: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
on the prototype declaration lines. what's the problem?

```
typedef struct queue{
int count;
int first;
int last;
int *q;
};

void init_queue(queue *q);
void enqueue(queue *q, int x);
int dequeue(queue *q);
int empty(queue *q);
```

Comment: @payne on all the prototype lines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never finished your typedef. You probably meant to do:

```
typedef struct queue{
int count;
int first;
int last;
int *q;
} queue;
```

You need to define an alias for your type at the end of the typedef. If you didn't have a typedef, you'd have to write your prototypes like so:

```
void init_queue(struct queue *q);
// etc.
```